# How do I create a snapshot based on orphan disk

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to create a snapshot of all the orphan disks within my resources. First I like to find all the orphan disks within resource and then delete all the orphan disks but before i delete it, I like to create snapshot. Can someone help me out with this. I am new to azure powershell. This will be my first powershell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Login-AzAccount

$rg = '<name of resource group that to store your snapshot , recommand you create a new one>'

$disks = Get-AzDisk 

foreach ($disk in $disks) {
    if(!$disk.ManagedBy){
         $snapconfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -Location $disk.Location -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy
         #create snapshot
         New-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg -SnapshotName $disk.Name  -Snapshot $snapconfig  

         #remove disk .it is strongly recommand that make sure your have created snapshot successfully to run this command
         remove-azdisk -ResourceGroupName $disk.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $disk.Name -Force
    }
}
```